# Using the %>% pipe, and dot (.) notation

Tags: r, magrittr

When using `map` on a nested data_frame, I do not understand why the latter two version give an error, how should I use the dot (`.`)?

```
library(tidyverse)
# dummy data
df <- tibble(id = rep(1:10, each = 10), 
                 val = runif(100))
df <- nest(df, -id)

# works as expected
map(df$data, min)
df %>% .$data %>% map(., min)

# gives an error
df %>% map(.$data, min)
# Error: Don't know how to index with object of type list at level 1

df %>% map(data, min)
```

Answer (score 55, accepted):

The problem isn't `map`, but rather how the `%>%` pipe deals with the `.`. Consider the following examples (remember that `/` is a two argument function in R):

##### Simple piping:

```
1 %>% `/`(2)
```

Is equivalent to `` `/`(1, 2) `` or `1 / 2` and gives `0.5`.

It is also equivalent to `` 1 %>% `/`(., 2) ``.

##### Simple `.` use:

```
1 %>% `/`(2, .)
```

Is equivalent to `` `/`(2, 1) `` or `2 / 1` and gives `2`.

You can see that `1` is no longer used as the first argument, but only as the second.

##### Other `.` use:

This *doesn't* work however, when subsetting the `.`:

```
list(a = 1) %>% `/`(.$a, 2)
```

> ```
> Error in `/`(., .$a, 2) : operator needs one or two arguments
> ```

We can see that `.` got injected twice, as the first argument and subsetted in the second argument. An expression like `.$a` is sometimes referred to as a *nested function call* (the `$` function is used inside the `/` function, in this case).

We use braces to avoid first argument injection:

```
list(a = 1) %>% { `/`(.$a, 2) }
```

Gives 0.5 again.

##### Actual problem:

You are actually calling `map(df, df$data, min)`, not `map(df$data, min)`.

##### Solution:

Use braces:

```
df %>% { map(.$data, min) }
```

Also see the header *Using the dot for secondary purposes* in `` ?magrittr::`%>%` `` which reads:

> In particular, if the placeholder is only used in a nested function
> call, lhs will also be placed as the first argument! The reason for
> this is that in most use-cases this produces the most readable code.
> For example, `iris %>% subset(1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)` is equivalent to
> `iris %>% subset(., 1:nrow(.) %% 2 == 0)` but slightly more compact. It
> is possible to overrule this behavior by enclosing the rhs in braces.
> For example, `1:10 %>% {c(min(.), max(.))}` is equivalent to
> `c(min(1:10), max(1:10))`.