# When should we use curly brackets { } when piping with dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, magrittr

I found out that some expressions can only be piped if inside curly brackets (braces, `{ }`), for instance:

```
library(dplyr)
3 %>% {3 + .}
3 %>% {ifelse(. < 2, TRUE, FALSE)}
```

What are the rules behind the use of curly brackets when piping? When should we use it and with which expressions?

Comment: The curly brace appears to suppress the pipe from using the first argument in a function. http://qiita.com/aakansh9/items/c2c4d3f653162778b757 So to answer your question, whenever you want the passing of first argument to a function suppressed? :)

Comment: This is quite clearly documented. See `?"%>%"` under _Using the dot for secondary purposes_. Also see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/map-for-nested-data-frames/42386886#42386886).

Comment: @Axemanthank you, wans't aware of `?"%>%"`

Comment: @Axeman and Roman, This is a fairly common question, but we can't use it as a dupe target because it doesn't have a 'real' answer. Would either of you mind to compile your comments as an answer? Cheers.

Comment: @Roman Luštrik Couldn't ping both you and Axeman in the post above, so here we go. I know the `{}` topic has been elaborated in other posts, but I reckon this question is most to the point.

Comment: @Henrik, I think I basically wrote my answer in the link above. Can one link to that, perhaps?

Comment: @Axeman then maybe hammer as dupe?