# Trying to understand what the {} does when placed after the pipe operator (%>%)

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, purrr, magrittr

In this [tutorial](https://jennybc.github.io/purrr-tutorial/ls01_map-name-position-shortcuts.html), there is the following code:

```
library(repurrrsive)
library(listviewer)
library(purrr)
library(tibble)
got_chars %>% {
  tibble(
       name = map_chr(., "name"),
    culture = map_chr(., "culture"),
     gender = map_chr(., "gender"),       
         id = map_int(., "id"),
       born = map_chr(., "born"),
      alive = map_lgl(., "alive")
  )
}
```

And the explanation provided says: "The dot `.` above is the placeholder for the primary input: got_chars in this case. The curly braces `{}` surrounding the `tibble()` call prevent got_chars from being passed in as the first argument of `tibble()`"

I'd like an explanation to what the `{}` are doing, and is this a general r property, or one exclusive to `purrr`? Is this similar to defining a nameless function such as `function(x){ x + 1}`?

Comment: I notice that `rnorm(100000) %>% {sum(.)/length(.)}` does the same thing as: `rnorm(100000) %>% (function(.){sum(.)/length(.)})`, So I believe my intuition is correct. I'm still unclear on whether this is a general r property is some black magic from the tidyverse.

Comment: The comments here [When should we use curly brackets when piping with dplyr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623497/when-should-we-use-curly-brackets-when-piping-with-dplyr) point you to relevant docs.

Comment: Nice comments there, Henrik, I was just about to do the same.

Comment: I guess the only followup question I have is: are the curly brackets performing the same function that they do when I am defining a function? I guess I never really thought about what they do