# Unexpected dplyr::bind_rows() behavior

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, magrittr

### Short Version:

I'm encountering an error with `dplyr::bind_rows()` which I don't understand. I want to split my data based on some condition (e.g. `a == 1`), operate on one part (e.g. `b = b * 10`), and bind it back to the other part using `dplyr::bind_rows()` in a single pipe chain. It works fine if I provide the first input to the two parts explictly, but if instead I pipe them in with `.` it complains about the data type of agrument 2.

Here's a MRE of the issue:

```r
library(tidyverse)

# sim data
d <- tibble(a = 1:4, b = 1:4)

# works when 'd' is supplied directly to bind_rows()
bind_rows(d %>% filter(a == 1),
          d %>% filter(!a == 1) %>% mutate(b = b * 10))
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2    20
#> 3     3    30
#> 4     4    40


# fails when 'd' is piped in to bind_rows()
d %>%
  bind_rows(. %>% filter(a == 1),
            . %>% filter(!a == 1) %>% mutate(b = b * 10))
#> Error: Argument 2 must be a data frame or a named atomic vector.
```

### Long Version:

If I capture what the `bind_rows()` call is getting as input as a `list()` instead, I can see that two unexpected (to me) things are happening.

1. Instead of evaluating the pipe chains I provided it seems to just capure them as a [functional sequence](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/reference/functions.html).
2. I can see that the input (`.`) is invisibly being provided in addition to the two explict arguments, so I get 3 items instead of 2 in the list.

```r
# capture intermediate values for diagnostics
d %>%
  list(. %>% filter(a == 1),
            . %>% filter(!a == 1) %>% mutate(b = b * 10))
#> [[1]]
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <int> <int>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2     2
#> 3     3     3
#> 4     4     4
#> 
#> [[2]]
#> Functional sequence with the following components:
#> 
#>  1. filter(., a == 1)
#> 
#> Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions. 
#> 
#> [[3]]
#> Functional sequence with the following components:
#> 
#>  1. filter(., !a == 1)
#>  2. mutate(., b = b * 10)
#> 
#> Use 'functions' to extract the individual functions.
```

This leads me to the following inelegant solution where I solve the first problem by piping to the inner function which seems to force evaluation correctly (for reasons I don't understand) and then solve the second problem by subsetting the `list` prior to performing the `bind_rows()` operation.

```r
# hack solution to force eval and clean duplicated input
d %>%
  list(filter(., a == 1),
       filter(., !a == 1) %>% mutate(b = b * 10)) %>%
  .[-1] %>% 
  bind_rows()
#> # A tibble: 4 x 2
#>       a     b
#>   <int> <dbl>
#> 1     1     1
#> 2     2    20
#> 3     3    30
#> 4     4    40
```

<sup>Created on 2022-01-24 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

It seems like it might be related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52506031/13210554) issue, but I can't quite see how. It would be great to understand why this is happening and find a way code this without the need to assign intermediate variables or do this weird hack to subset the intermediate list.

---

##### EDIT:

Knowing this was related to curly braces (`{}`) enabled me to find a few more helpful links:
[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623497/when-should-we-use-curly-brackets-when-piping-with-dplyr?noredirect=1&lq=1), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48102734/trying-to-understand-what-the-does-when-placed-after-the-pipe-operator), [3](https://thatdatatho.com/tutorial-about-magrittrs-pipe-operator-and-placeholders/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we want to use `.`, then block it with scope operator (`{}`)

```
library(dplyr)
d %>%
   {
  bind_rows({.} %>% filter(a == 1),
            {.} %>% filter(!a == 1) %>% mutate(b = b * 10))
   }
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 4 × 2
      a     b
  <int> <dbl>
1     1     1
2     2    20
3     3    30
4     4    40
```

Comment: Wow - that's great to know, thanks! It's very briefly documented [here](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/#re-using-the-placeholder-for-attributes)