# pipes w/ `stopifnot()` and `testit::assert()`

Tags: r

How do I pipe in a result to [`stopifnot()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/stopifnot.html) and [`testit::assert()`](https://CRAN.R-project.org/package=testit)?

```
library(magrittr)

0 %>% 
  testit::assert("gotta be small", . < 10)  
# Error: . is not TRUE

0 %>% 
  testit::assert(. < 10)  
# Error: . is not TRUE

0 %>% 
  stopifnot(. < 10)
# Error in function_list[[k]](value) : . is not TRUE
```

Works:

```
testit::assert(0 < 10)  
stopifnot(0 < 10)
```

I'm assuming they're not acting like a conventional function like `add()` because they're evaluating an expression.  I'm guessing I should package the argument differently, so it's interpreted correctly by their [`match.call()`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/match.call.html) calls, but I'm not sure how to.

Comment: Use braces `0 %>% {testit::assert("gotta be small", . < 10)}`.  That will get the `.` value to the right place. You need to do this when you want to pass the `.` as part of an expression rather than a parameter on it's own.

Comment: @MrFlick is right. This is [related post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623497/when-should-we-use-curly-brackets-when-piping-with-dplyr?noredirect=1&lq=1).

Comment: That helps, and I voted to close it as a duplicate.  Even knowing the answer, I'm still not sure how I would have searched for the answer differently; there aren't any terms or keywords I can grab on to.  The closest I see are "secondary purpose" or "expression".