# R dplyr using across() efficiently with mutate() and case_when()

Tags: r, dplyr

Here is data:

```
library(tidyverse)
set.seed(1234)
df1 <- tibble(
  S1 = rnorm(5), 
  S2 = rnorm(5), 
  S3 = rnorm(5), 
  S4 = rnorm(5), 
)
```

I want to apply an arithmetic transformation, truncate the distribution, and format values as integers. This code works:

```
df2 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~
                  round(. * 10) + 50),
         across(
           everything(),
           ~
             case_when(. < 45 ~ 45,
                       . > 55 ~ 55,
                       TRUE ~ .) %>%
             as.integer(.)
         ))
```

But when I make the code more concise, placing all three operations within a single instance of `across()`, as in:

```
df3 <- df1 %>%
  mutate(across(everything(),
                ~
                  round(. * 10) + 50) %>% 
                    case_when(. < 45 ~ 45,
                       . > 55 ~ 55,
                       TRUE ~ .) %>%
             as.integer(.)
         )
```

I get this error:

```
Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `..1`.
x Case 1 (`.`) must be a two-sided formula, not a `tbl_df/tbl/data.frame` object.
ℹ Input `..1` is ``%>%`(...)`.
```

Not sure what I'm doing wrong. Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can place them in a block `{}`

```
df1 %>%
    mutate(across(everything(), ~
    (round(. * 10) + 50) %>%
      {case_when(. < 45 ~ 45, . > 55 ~ 55, TRUE ~ .)} %>% 
    as.integer ))
# A tibble: 5 x 4
#     S1    S2    S3    S4
#  <int> <int> <int> <int>
#1    45    55    45    49
#2    53    45    45    45
#3    55    45    45    45
#4    45    45    51    45
#5    54    45    55    55
```

---

Or create a temporary object within `{}` and apply `case_when` on it

```
df1 %>%
     mutate(across(everything(), ~ {
         tmp <- round(. * 10 ) + 50
         as.integer(case_when(tmp < 45 ~ 45, tmp > 55  ~ 55, TRUE ~ tmp))
      }))
```

Comment: Thank you. How do the curly braces change how R evaluates the code? I see that it does work, I still don't understand the mechanism.

Comment: @DSH Can you check [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42623497/when-should-we-use-curly-brackets-when-piping-with-dplyr?noredirect=1&lq=1)

Comment: Thanks - that's the explanation I was looking for!