# Using `%>%` with `lm` and `rbind`

Tags: r, lm, magrittr

I have a dataframe `Z` looking like

```
t  x  y  d
0  1  2  1
1  2  3  1
2  3  4  1
0  1  2  2
1  2  3  2
2  3  4  2
```

with `d` being a factor column. I know want to fit a linear model with `lm` to `y` over `t` for both factors in `d` and add it as a new column to the dataframe.

I tried

```
Z %>%
  filter(d == 1) %>%
  lm(y ~ t)
```

but this gives me an error saying `"Error in as.data.frame.default(data) : 
  cannot coerce class ""formula"" to a data.frame"`. But

```
lm(y ~ t, data = Z)
```

works fine. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Related: [Using the %>% pipe, and dot (.) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We need to extract the `data` and `.` represents the data object

```
Z %>% 
  filter(d == 1) %>% 
  lm(y ~ t, data = .)
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ t, data = .)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            t  
#          2            1
```

---

Within the `summarise/mutate/group_by` and other tidyverse functions, we can simply pass the column name.  Here, either we need to get the columns from within the environment of data or create a `list` output in `summarise`

```
library(magrittr)    
Z %>%
  filter(d ==1 ) %>%
  summarise(lmout = list(lm(y ~ t))) %>%
  pull(lmout) %>%
  extract2(1)
#Call:
#lm(formula = y ~ t)

#Coefficients:
#(Intercept)            t  
#          2            1
```

Comment: Thanks! What are the last two lines doing?

Comment: @Pascal In the `summarise`, I wrapped it with `list`, so it is a `list` column.  with `pull`, the column is extracted as a list of length 1, with `extract2` from `magrittr`, the list element is extracted.  `summarise` returns a single element as output but the `lm` output is a specialized structure and that is the reason to wrap it in `list`

Comment: Thus, I can extract the `fitted.values` by `extract2(5)`?

Comment: @Pascal  The `extract2` is to extract the model object that is in the list.  Now, you may have to extract again the values from the model object