# piping a vector into all() to test equality

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr, magrittr

I'm trying to pipe a vector into an `all()` statement to check if all elements are equal to a certain value. I figure I need to use the exposition pipe `%$%` since `all()` does not have a built-in data argument. My attempt leads to an error:

```r
library(tidyverse)
library(magrittr)

vec <- c("a", "b", "a")

vec %>%
  keep(!grepl("b", .)) %$%
  all(. == "a")
#> Error in eval(substitute(expr), data, enclos = parent.frame()): invalid 'envir' argument of type 'character'
```

If I break the pipe before `all()` and assign the output to an object `p`, and then pass `p` to `all()` as a second command it works fine:

```r
vec %>%
  keep(!grepl("b", .)) -> p

all(p == "a")
#> [1] TRUE
```

I don't understand why this works while my first attempt does not. I'd like to be able to do this in a single pipe that results in `TRUE`.

If `vec` is instead a `tibble` the following works:

```r
vec <- tibble(var = c("a", "b", "a"))

vec %>%
  filter(!grepl("b", var)) %$%
  all(.$var == "a")
#> [1] TRUE
```

This doesn't suit my purposes as well, and I'd for my own understanding to know why my first attempt does not work.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The way pipe works is it takes the left-hand side of the pipe operator and passes it as a first argument to the right hand side function. So here, in this case as we need to modify the data argument to `all` , we need to stop pipe from passing the LHS to the RHS. We can do that by using `{}`.

```
library(magrittr)

vec %>% purrr::keep(!grepl("b", .)) %>% {all(. == 'a')}
#[1] TRUE
```

---

In `vec` , let's check if all the elements are either `"a"` or "`b`". We can use `%in%` here.

```
vec <- c("a", "b", "a")
```

Plain version without pipes would be :

```
all(vec %in% c('a', 'b'))
#[1] TRUE
```

With pipes, if we try

```
vec %>% all(. %in% c('a', 'b'))
```

We get

```
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
>   In all(., . %in% c("a", "b")) :
>     coercing argument of type 'character' to logical

what is happening here is

```
all(vec, vec %in% c('a', 'b'))
#[1] NA
```

> Warning message:
>   In all(vec, vec %in% c("a", "b")) :
>     coercing argument of type 'character' to logical

which returns the same message.

To avoid this we use `{}`

```
vec %>% {all(. %in% c('a', 'b'))}
#[1] TRUE
```

which gives us the expected answer.

Comment: why does the issue not occur in the last example, then?

Comment: @lost `%$%` and `%>%` are two different functions. `%$%` doesn't pass output of the previous function as first argument to next function.

Comment: I know they are different functions. I don't quite follow why we need to stop the pipe from passing the LHS to the RHS -- isn't that what we're trying to do?

Comment: I'm familiar with the usage of curly brackets to keep `%>%` from injecting `.` twice, such as discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation), but it seems curly brackets are serving a different purpose in this case?

Comment: thanks for the edit. It is helpful. Would I be right in concluding that in my last example, `%$% all(.$var == "a")` does not throw an error because subsetting `.` causes the first argument piping to be suppressed, such that it is not interpreted as `%$% all(., .$var == "a")`?

Comment: `%$%` doesn't pass LHS output as first argument to RHS function. Check `mtcars %$% subset(cyl > 6)` vs `mtcars %>% subset(cyl > 6)`. However, issue looks like that `%$%` doesn't work for vectors. See `vec %$% .` and `mtcars %$% .` hence you get an error in first case. This is also mentioned in `?\`%$%\`` where `lhs` is `A list, environment, or a data.frame.`

Comment: Gotcha. I did not realize `%$%` was not intended for vectors. I think that was the biggest source of confusion for me. Thanks again.