# Applying is.na() function in a vector with pipe function

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe

I was experimenting with the `pipe` function from `dplyr`, and running below code without success -

```
library(dplyr)
12 %>% ifelse(is.na(.), FALSE, TRUE)
### Error in ifelse(., is.na(.), FALSE, TRUE) : unused argument (TRUE)
```

Any pointer why I am getting this error? What is the correct approach if I want to use `pipe`?

Comment: A similar situation was discussed recently https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60106626/piping-a-vector-into-all-to-test-equality/60106676#60106676

Comment: Please think about the value of logical conditions, such as `is.na`, before coding constructs like `ifelse(logical_condition, FALSE, TRUE)`. The result of `logical_condition` **already is a logical value**.

Comment: @RuiBarradas In my code I was trying convert a NA to FALSE to eliminate the chance of any break in subsequent codes

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using the %>% pipe, and dot (.) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation)

Comment: OK, but something like `%>% mutate(new_value = !is.na(.))` is better.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several possibilities:

**Using brackets**: As @tmfmnk pointed out, one should use `{}` to get that behavior in `pipe`:

```
 library(dplyr)
 vec <- c(12,13, NA)
 vec %>% {ifelse(is.na(.), FALSE,TRUE)}
 # TRUE  TRUE FALSE
```

**Unnesting**: Alternatively, as @Ands pointed out, one can unnest the functions:

```
12 %>% is.na %>% ifelse(FALSE, TRUE)
```

Answer (score 3):

We can use `is.na` directly in the pipeline rather than nesting it:

```
12 %>% is.na %>% ifelse(FALSE, TRUE)
```

or

```
12 %>% is.na %>% `!`
```

or

```
library(magrittr)
12 %>% is.na %>% not
```

or

```
12 %>% (is.na %>% Negate)
```

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to unnest the functions further.

```
12 %>% is.na %>% ifelse(FALSE, TRUE)
# TRUE
```

Answer (score 0):

```
library(dplyr)
12 %>% ifelse(is.na(.), FALSE)
#FALSE
```

this works for me

Comment: But `c(12, NA) %>% ifelse(is.na(.), FALSE)` doesn't remove the `NA`, which was the question's point.