# Can't use placeholder with magrittr in r

Tags: r, dplyr, placeholder

I was curious why the code below can not run. I thought the dot `.` ia a palceholder and pass `mtcats` to the position.

```
table(mtcars$cyl)

mtcars %>% table(.$cyl)
```

Comment: Use `{}` as explained here [Using the %>% pipe, and dot (.) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation)

Comment: hi please try this hope this will help.```mtcars %>% { table(mtcars$cyl) }``` as mention in above comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The pipe `%>%` pastes the object on the left as the first argument into the
function on the right. So you basically execute:

```r
table(mtcars, mtcars$cyl)
#> Error in table(mtcars, mtcars$cyl): all arguments must have the same length
```

As agr0naut91 comments, this can be fixed with using curly brackets:

```r
library(magrittr)

mtcars %>% {table(.$cyl)}
#> 
#>  4  6  8 
#> 11  7 14
```

This works whenever you want to pipe into a function that is not pipe
friendly, which usually means that it doesn’t have a `data.frame` argument
as the first argument.
Using `dplyr::count()` you can get an output that is comparable to `base::table()`,
without having to use the curly brackets.

```r
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

mtcars %>% count(cyl)
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>     cyl     n
#>   <dbl> <int>
#> 1     4    11
#> 2     6     7
#> 3     8    14
```