# Pipe/dplyr friendly way to filter non zero elements of a vector

Tags: r, dplyr, pipe, tidyverse

Surprisingly I am not finding an answer to this easy question. I need a pipe-friendly way to count the number of non-zero elements in a vector.

Without piping:

```
v <- c(1.1,2.2,0,0)
length(which(v != 0))
```

When I try to do this with pipes I get an error

```
v %>% which(. != 0) %>% length
Error in which(., . != 0) : argument to 'which' is not logical
```

A dplyr solution would also help

Comment: Related, more general post: [Using the %>% pipe, and dot (.) notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here are some different options:

First, we can use `{}` with your original form:

```
v %>% {which(. != 0)} %>% length
#[1] 2
```

Or we could use `{}` to allow us to repeat `.`:

```
v %>% {.[. != 0]} %>% length
#[1] 2
```

Or we could use `subset` from Base R:

```
v %>% subset(. != 0) %>% length
#[1] 2
```

Answer (score 2):

One way using `magrittr` could be:

```
v %>%
 equals(0) %>%
 not() %>%
 sum()

[1] 2
```

Comment: I didn't realize there were all these functions in `help("extract","magrittr")`. Thanks for the introduction.

Answer (score 1):

We can convert to `tibble` and `filter`

```
library(dplyr)
tibble(v) %>% 
  filter(v != 0) %>%
  nrow
#[1] 2
```