# correlation at the end of a pipe operation

Tags: r, purrr

I am trying to get a correlation between two variables at the end of a pipe operation, why don't these work?

```
library(tidyverse)
iris %>% 
  map(~cor(.$Sepal.Length, .$Sepal.Width, use = "complete.obs"))

#or
iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% 
  map2(~cor(.x, .y, use = "complete.obs"))
```

thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It doesn't need a `map` as this can be done within `summarise`

```
library(dplyr)
iris %>% 
  summarise(out = cor(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, use = "complete.obs"))
#       out
#1 -0.1175698
```

With `map2`, the tasks performed are applying a function on each corresponding element of the the concerned columns, where as the `cor` is on the full column taken as a single unit

The second option is doing similar one as

```
Map(cor, iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width,
        MoreArgs = list(use = 'complete.obs'))

iris %>% 
  dplyr::select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% 
  {map2(.$Sepal.Length, .$Sepal.Width, .f = cor, use = "complete.obs")}
```

Or with `pmap`

```
iris %>%
   dplyr::select(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width) %>% 
   pmap(~ cor(.x, .y, use = "complete.obs"))
```

NOTE: all of them returns `NA` as the number of observations are 1

Answer (score 6):

Don't forget about `%$%` !

```r
library(magrittr)

iris %$% 
  cor(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, use = "complete.obs")
#> [1] -0.1175698
```

<sup>Created on 2021-03-02 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Answer (score 5):

`map` and `map2` are for iteration - you don't want to iterate over anything, you just want to call `cor` on two columns. I'd suggest

```
iris %>%
  with(cor(Sepal.Length, Sepal.Width, use = "complete.obs"))
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @akrun I remembered that this may also work which it does, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation)

```
iris %>%    
  {(cor(.$Sepal.Length, .$Sepal.Width, use = "complete.obs"))}
```