# Plotting only some from_points dependent on another column

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to plot only a subset of my data, dependent on another column. I want to do this within ggplot, not by subsetting my data. As a simple example:

```
ggplot(mtcars, aes(x=hp, y=mpg) +
geom_point()
```

How would I get geom_point to only plot points with cyl == 4?

In my real data it’d be dependent on the value of another column being TRUE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case I think it's best to do the `filter`ing inside the individual geom layers since they're all different subsets of the same data source. Here are a couple of options on how to do this. I think option 1 is much cleaner code.

#### Option 1

If you look at the documentation for any `geom_*()` function you'll see that there are actually 3 options for what to provide as `data`.

> If `NULL`, the default, the data is inherited from the plot data as
> specified in the call to `ggplot()`.
>
> A `data.frame`, or other object, will override the plot data. All
> objects will be fortified to produce a data frame. See `fortify()` for
> which variables will be created.
>
> A `function` will be called with a single argument, the plot data. The
> return value must be a `data.frame`, and will be used as the layer data.
> A `function` can be created from a formula (e.g. `~ head(.x, 10)`).

This last option can be used here to perform additional manipulation/filtering on your data prior to using it in a particular `geom_*()` layer.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# give function as data
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(newcol = cyl * wt) %>%
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(data = ~filter(.x, cyl > 4 & qsec < 17),
                 aes(x = hp, y = mpg), color = "red") +
      geom_text(data = ~filter(.x, newcol < 10 | disp < 90),
                aes(x = hp, y = mpg, label = car))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

#### Option 2

Second, you could use capture the output of {magrittr} pipe (`%>%`) as `.` and filter inside the `geom_*()`'s `data` argument. In order to prevent the output of `%>%` going in as the first argument you need to embrace the `ggplot()` call in curly braces `{}` and then also wrap the pipe output in curly braces, like this: `{.}`. In some cases, it will work fine without this treatment since `data` can be the first argument, but not always depending on how you construct this. Therefore it's safest to use the `{}` approach.

This somewhat unintuitive behaviour of the {magrittr} pipe is lightly documented [here](https://magrittr.tidyverse.org/#re-using-the-placeholder-for-attributes).
There's also a nice explanation of it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42386886/13210554) answer.

You can combine multiple conditions in the `filter` operation by connecting then with logical OR (`|`) or AND (`&`) operators.

```r
library(tidyverse)

# works with or without {}
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(newcol = cyl * wt) %>%
  rownames_to_column("car") %>% 
  {
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(data = {.} %>% filter(cyl > 4 & qsec < 17),
                 aes(x = hp, y = mpg), color = "red") +
      geom_text(data = {.} %>% filter(newcol < 10 | disp < 90),
                aes(x = hp, y = mpg, label = car))
  }
```

[image]

```r
# error without {}
mtcars %>% 
  mutate(newcol = cyl * wt) %>%
  rownames_to_column("car") %>%
    ggplot() +
      geom_point(data = filter(., cyl > 4 & qsec < 17),
                 aes(x = hp, y = mpg), color = "red") +
      geom_text(data = filter(., newcol < 10 | disp < 90),
                aes(x = hp, y = mpg, label = car))
#> Error in filter(., cyl > 4 & qsec < 17): object '.' not found
```

<sup>Created on 2022-02-20 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Comment: Why do you need the curly braces? Seems to work without them

Comment: Actually, you're right, In this case it still works when you remove them. However depending on the order of arguments in each geom layer I think it might break in some cases, so this is still the safest way to write it. This is discussed in more detail [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation/42386886#42386886), [here](https://qiita.com/aakansh9/items/c2c4d3f653162778b757), and [here](https://thatdatatho.com/tutorial-about-magrittrs-pipe-operator-and-placeholders/).

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this can be done with geom_point(data = . %>% filter(newcol>4), color="red")