# Using pull() with c() in R to combine vectors

Tags: r, vector

I've just come across the pull() function and the output is somehow different when using it in a pipeline. See this example:

```
## What's the problem with pull()?
##
install.packages("hflights")
library(hflights)
library(magrittr)

## Here we create two vectors
##
origins <- pull(hflights, Origin)
destinations <- pull(hflights, Dest)

## Here we combine them into one vector and retrieve the unique values:
##

c(origins, destinations) %>% unique()

## So what's the problem with this?:
## It returns a nested list.

hflights %>% c(pull(.,Origin), pull(.,Dest)) %>% unique()
```

Comment: Instead of using two `pull`s, `select` the columns of interest and `unlist` or `flatten` i.e. `hflights %>% select(Origin, Dest) %>% flatten_chr %>% unique` or `hflights %>% select(Origin, Dest) %>% invoke(c, .) %>% unique`

Comment: R also has a dedication function for `unique(c(x, y))` which is `union()`: `do.call(union, hflights[c('Origin', 'Dest')] |> unname())`

Comment: While these are perfectly fine alternatives, my interest was in why I couldn't c() the vectors returned from pull() in the usual way. Like Perl, with R "there's more than one way to do it."

Answer (score 2):

you will get your expected result by using curly braces around the complex middle section

```
hflights %>% {c(pull(.,Origin), pull(.,Dest)) }%>% unique()
```

Comment: I wonder why, any hint?

Comment: That certainly does work, but I second Mael's question. What's special about enclosing that part in curly braces?

Comment: The docs say  `Each rhs is essentially a one-expression body of a unary function. Therefore defining lambdas in magrittr is very natural, and as the definitions of regular functions: if more than a single expression is needed one encloses the body in a pair of braces, { rhs }. However, note that within braces there are no "first-argument rule": it will be exactly like writing a unary function where the argument name is "." (the dot).`

Comment: @CharlesKnell https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42385010/using-the-pipe-and-dot-notation/42386886 also gives a good explanation